# Postgresql query by json key condition

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I've a table with JSON column and want to select rows where JSON key 'k' has value 'value'.  Json may consist of several pairs of [K,V].

```json
[
  {"k":"esr:code","v":"800539"},
  {"k":"lit","v":"yes"},
  {"k":"name","v":"5 км"},
  {"k":"railway","v":"halt"},
  {"k":"uic_ref","v":"2040757"}
]
```

I tried to use the next query, but it's wrong.

```
SELECT * 
FROM public.node 
where ((node.tags)::json->>'k' like 'name')
```

How I can fix it, if it's possible?)

Where node - table name, tags - json column.

Comment: Why isn't `tags` defined as `jsonb` (or at least `json`)  if you store a JSON value in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JSONB [contains operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) `@>`

```
SELECT * 
FROM public.node 
where node.tags @> '[{"k","name"}]';
```

This will do an exact match against `name`. Your usage of `like` might indicate you are looking for a partial match - however as your `like` condition doesn't use a wildcard it's the same as `=`.

This assumes that `tags` is defined as `jsonb` (which it should be). If it's not you need to cast it: `node.tags::jsonb`